# Re-indexing, without iterative find. matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

Let there be 2 matrices, X and T. X holds the coordinates of points (size Nx3) and T has 4 pointers per row pointing to X (Mx4).

At some point of my code some points of X are deleted. Thus, T becomes outdated and should be updated to point at the correct point values. To do this, I iteratively search the index of a point to find its position in a new matrix holding positions. However, this needs Mx4 'find' calls, which is an overkill I think.

Example: T(1,:)= 1 2 3 4. If the original X(4,:) is deleted, the T(1,4) points at the wrong point now.

One way to tackle this, might be to compute how points have been deleted till index 'i'.

Any better idea, more 'matlab' style?

Comment: For a better understanding of the problem I would ask you to show the code you are using with a minimal example of a data set.

Comment: _At some point of my code some points of X are deleted_ Please, post your code. Beside, what about to update `T` just when you delete the points in `X`?

Comment: I assume this is edges and vertices of a 3D tetrahedral mesh? If you delete something in X, what should happen with the value in T? delete the whole row of T? you say that T points at the wrong point, but what is the right thing to do? Can you give an example with N=5, M=2?

Comment: It is vertices and triangles in a 3D volumetric mesh. At some point, I drop all the inside points of the volume and continue with the points only on the surface of the volume. This means that the indexing might become irrelevant. Imagine a triangle made up by points 1,2,100. If 1 point between 1 and 100 was a point inside the volume, then the 'previously' point number 100 might have become point number 99,98 or whatever. Is it clearer now?